# Getting Java to convert from generic class to generic object

Tags: java, class, generics, casting

Basically, I have three functions:

```
Class<? extends Base> getClass();

T ObjectFromClass(Class<T> classOfT);

<T extends Base> getObject(){
   return ObjectFromClass(getClass());
}
```

This code gives me the following compiler error:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? extends Base to T.

Now this can be fixed by casting the return as a (T). However, as far as I can tell, since the Class itself must extend Base, the resulting object must extend Base as well, and thus this return is type-safe.

Am I wrong?

If I'm not, is there a way to make it so I do not have to cast at any point in the process?

Edit: I was asked for more context:

I am using gson to convert to/from json to call a webservice. The idea is I have a bunch of Request and Response Objects for the various calls I have to make. I have a generic getResponse(Request) function, I would like it to automatically return the correct response type based on the request. I gave each request a getResponseType() function which returns the class of the response that it corresponds too. So I call

```
T<extends Response> getResponse(Request request){ 
     ///do work to get webResponse 
     return gson.fromJson(webResponse, request.getResponseType()); 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context, such as an example of where/how you would use this?

Comment: I added my response to the main question, since it seems like you can't do as much formatting in a response.

Comment: your code is not syntactically correct

Answer (score 1):

`getClass()` returns anything that extends `Base`, so nothing promises me that this will be the same T as in your other methods.

For the sake of the example, let's say Base is Object. now let's say that `getClass()` will return Integer - it's valid since it extends Object. nothing assures you that T from `<T extends Base> getObject()` is not String for example - it also extends Object (remember this is compilation time- you can't make assumptions about getClass unless they all use the same T which is defined in the class declaration.

If T is defined in the methods, you can't make any assumptions about it being the same T across two methods

Comment: yes, but `ObjectFromClass` returns some T (not neccesariliy extends Base), so you can't return this as the return type of `getObject()` which requires it to extend Base

Comment: Now we're getting to the root of my question. If the Class of the object is of type Class<? extends Base> how can the Object not extend Base?

Comment: so it should be a typed class, with `<T extends Base>` in the class declaration, and all methods should use this T, not with `<extends Base>` in each of the methods